# Reattaching a detatched object with update() causes LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have spent some time on the forum and googling and I have not found a solution to this problem.

I am currently struggling to reattach an object to the session.

Here is basically what I do:

```
dao.update(myPersistentObject);
myPersistentObject.getLazyProperty();
endTransaction();
```

I get an LazyInitializationException when I am accessing Lazy fields of an object that I just have reattached to the session.

I am in a transaction and I must make an update (not a lock()) because my object has changed and is dirty.

Does anybody have a suggestion to resolve this problem?

I do not understand why this is happening because my object is supposed to be reattached and therefore I must be able to access lazily my properties....

Thanks!

Comment: Normally an update would return the attached object. You are probably still using the detached one. Have a look at the dao method. The result of `em.merge(entity)` should be returned.

Comment: Are you in an Java EE environment? If so, is your DAO an EJB? What's the transaction attribute of your `update` method?

Comment: Can you detail your dao implementation? What the `update` method does?

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. 
1.  Update is void, so it does not pass an object.
2.  DAO just calls sessionFactory.update(Object)

 void update(Object object) - Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given detached instance.

Comment: Oh and I am not using EJBs, just POJOs unfortunately.